# How to pass IPv6 parameter for snmp session creation using

Tags: perl, snmp, ipv6, net-snmp, snmpd

I am using SNMP package to create SNMPv3 session. But I am not sure how to pass transport information as UDP6 as I think default behavior is UDP. As far as I know that when use `Net::SNMP` to create session then we have "domain" parameter to classify between ipv4 and ipv6 address . But the same is not applicable to `SNMP::Session`. Can you please let me know how to pass transport information?

```
new SNMP::Session(DestHost      => $self->{'ip'},
                                                         version       => 3,
                                                         RemotePort    => $self->{'port'},
                                                         SecEngineId   => ‘0x8888233356',
                                                         SecName       => $hashVal{'userName'},
                                                         AuthProto     => $authProto,
                                                         AuthPass      => $hashVal{'authPW'},
                                                         PrivProto     => $privProto,
                                                         PrivPass      => $hashVal{'privPW'},
                                                         SecLevel      => $hashVal{‘secLevel’');
```